# Control is stuck with first instance of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, processbuilder

I'm starting this thread which basically executes a system call using ProcessBuilder.

```
Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
new Thread(threadJob).start();
```

This thread executes following Process Builder using its run() method:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();

    // Read output
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null, previous = null;
    while ((line = brin.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.equals(previous)) {
            previous = line;
            out.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    }
```

When this thread is successfully executed, I start a different thread inside it to launch xterm using ProcessBuilder:

```
    if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
        Runnable threadJob2 = new XRunnable();
        new Thread(threadJob2).start(); 
    }
```

Xterm is started successfully using following code in run() method of XRunnable():

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = pb.start();

    // Read output
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader brin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null, previous = null;
    while ((line = brin.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.equals(previous)) {
            previous = line;
            out.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    }

    if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Xterm killed")
    }
```

Issue I'm facing is that control is always stuck at this Xterm. If I launch another Xterm using same thread then it won't get control and I can't type anything in new Xterm window until previous one is killed. I think issue is that it is stuck at reading input stream of first Xterm and doesn't create a new input stream to read second Xterm. That's why I can type something once first Xterm is killed. Can anybody suggest ideas to resolve this issue ? I want to type something in each Xterm window I open using same thread code many times.

Comment: InputStream reads are blocking operations, so if you want to do multiple reads simultaneously, you'll need multiple threads...unless you want to switch to NIO, here.

Comment: My Bad ... Issue was not with code above. Code shown above is absolutely fine. Hash table was messing up threads ids. Thanks for reply David.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad ... Issue was not with code above. Code shown above is absolutely fine. Hash table was messing up threads ids. Thanks for reply David.